# Laravel 5 get relation data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've made application with Laravel 5.5 and I use MySQL  database. I have 2 tables
people: id, name, homeplanet_id
planets: id, name
And foreign key people.homeplanet_id references planets id

I also have 2 models: Person and Planet, and PersonController.
I can get Person's data in controller by using

```
Person::find($id)->getAttributes()
```

but it is like

```
[
    id => 1
    name => Name
    homeplanet_id => 1
]
```

How can I get data look like next

```
[
    id => 1
    name => Name
    homeplanet_id => Planet_name
]
```

Comment: @webDev , thank you, it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with() method,
Something like
$person = `Person::where(array())->with('planet')->get(); //You can fetch all related data by passing multiple values for method with()`

To print

```
{{$person->planet->name}} //where planet indicated the relation on person model as follows
```

Where `planet` indicated the relation on Person model.

**In our case**
Getting data
`$person = Person::where(array('id'=>$id))->with('planet')->get();`

And in **Person** model do something like following to fetch planet using `with()` method:

```
Person extends model{
   public function panet(){
      //your relation one to one, one to many etc.....whatever
   }
}
```

Try exploring **eager loading** in Laravel (eloquent)  and scoped query too.

Visit the link for Eager loading and everything will be done by the ORM itself.[Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 1):

> You may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources

So, if you want to get JSON, use resources. If you want this data format for Blade views, it's a bad idea to transform it. Just work with the data in Blade template:

```
{{ $person->name }} lives on the planet {{ $person->planet->name }}
```

Where `planet` is name of relationship defined in `Person` model:

```
public function planet()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Planet::class, 'homeplanet_id')
}
```